# Why is a globally set JS variable showing as undefined while using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to use Google Maps API geocode.  The full code is below and it worked the first time I tried, but now it's not bringing the map up and I can't figure out why.

I even tried adding "alert(data.status);" and it's returning a status of "OK".

When I inspect, the console says "latitude" is not defined here:

```
 var myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
```

Shouldn't the variable "latitude" that gets set when the DOM is loaded carry over to that line above, or did I do something wrong with variable scope?

```
  <style>
        #map {
        height:200px;
        width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var jsonLatLng ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Indianapolis&sensor=false';
            $.getJSON(jsonLatLng, function (data) {
                if (data.status="OK") {
                latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                longitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                } else { //A default lat/long so SOMETHING shows
                latitude = 38.99;
                longitude = -74.80;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And then this:

```
<div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: ''
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD98yPUHrWE8QZkSxWR1Fno3_yd70cPQbA&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: you didn't declare the variable longitude and latitude

Comment: You say `latitude` is a global variable but according to your posted code, it's not global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition between two asynchronous functions:

1. the ajax geocoder call
2. the asynchronous load of the Google Maps Javascript API v3 (`async defer &callback=initMap`)

Simplest way to resolve it is to call the geocoder in the initMap function (after the API has loaded).

```
function initMap() {
  var jsonLatLng = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Indianapolis';
  $.getJSON(jsonLatLng, function(data) {
    if (data.status == "OK") { // <======= fixed typo on this line
      latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      longitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    } else { //A default lat/long so SOMETHING shows
      latitude = 38.99;
      longitude = -74.80;
    }
    var myLatLng = {
      lat: latitude,
      lng: longitude
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: ''
    });
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6dtbeb1x/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var jsonLatLng = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Indianapolis';
  $.getJSON(jsonLatLng, function(data) {
    if (data.status == "OK") {
      latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      longitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    } else { //A default lat/long so SOMETHING shows
      latitude = 38.99;
      longitude = -74.80;
    }
    var myLatLng = {
      lat: latitude,
      lng: longitude
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: ''
    });
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare the variable longitude and latitude anywhere in your code. So you can do something like this:

```
var longitude, latitude;
$(function() {
  var jsonLatLng ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Indianapolis&sensor=false';
  $.getJSON(jsonLatLng, function (data) {
      if (data.status="OK") {
      latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      longitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      } else { //A default lat/long so SOMETHING shows
      latitude = 38.99;
      longitude = -74.80;
      }
  });
});
```

Also, if you put the var inside your function the variable will have a function scope, meaning it will be available only inside the function.

Comment: Thank you. Quick follow-up.  I am unable to use latitude or longitude in another function even tho I declared like you have it above.  In other words, I put "console.log(latitude);" in the "if" part and it shows a correct number, but if I move "console.log(latitude);" outside of the $.getJSON function, it shows as undefined.  Shouldn't it be defined everywhere since I declared it outside of the main function?

Comment: it should be declared everywhere. Can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: I set one up here: https://jsfiddle.net/v1nt9r65/3/, but I'm confused how to incorporate this part into the fiddle `<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD98yPUHrWE8QZkSxWR1Fno3_yd70cPQbA&callback=initMap">
    </script>` .  I added it as an external resource URL but dont think that is right